# How to memorise numeric sequence for English test?

Tags: listening, learning, learning-methods

I'm preparing for IELTS test and sometimes there are questions require memorizing long sequences such as weird names or phone numbers.

Normally in my mother lang, it's pretty easy to memorize such those sequences (short-time enough) to write it down.
But in IELTS tests, I tried a lot of tests with sequences but always failed (failed to remembers and/or failed to write down fast enough those series).
Is there any way to improve this ? Any website or suggestion ?

Comment: Interesting question but ELU is not for language learning. Try [ell.se] or [languagelearning.se]

Comment: Never heard of an oral sequence to repeat, as a question of learning English. The closest I can picture is selecting the next letter in a written sequence. For that chore, I write our alphabet once to spot the pattern in each: "AB EF IJ" gives M next. It's a math question, not language.

Comment: I remember being administered an IQ test as a teenager which included hearing and repeating successively longer strings of numbers, and I did quite well. The educational psychologist said so. I replied that I mentally split them up into groups of four like (UK) phone numbers. I don't think such a test is part of any English curriculum that I know of.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Agreed, this sounds much more like part of a cognitive ability test. The sort of thing designed to spot the beginnings of various mental problems such as Alzheimer's or dementia.

Comment: @PeterJennings - yes! I hate to think how I'd do these days.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Surely a UK 'phone number is normally split into a five-three-three? (Or four-three-three for some area codes).

Comment: @Showsni It depends entirely on how the individual finds easiest. All normal UK national numbers are 11 digits. Usually 4 for the area code plus an leading 0 and 6 for the actual number, For example Oxford is 01865 and a subscriber would be 01865 123456. As you say, one would memorise this in 3 groups of digits - 01865 123 456. Some numbers, however, have patterns which make them easier to remember in some other grouping. For example a fictitious mobile number might be easy to remember as 079709 44 123. Note the first 6 digits almost repeat, then there is a doubles digit.

Comment: @PeterJennings - I was a teenager _a very long time ago_. Also I grew up in London. You could dial numbers in London only. Mostly phone numbers in big cities had letters and numbers. London numbers were the first three letters of an exchange name (usually written in capitals) and four numerical digits. We were on the Tulse Hill exchange so our number was TULse Hill 1060. My pal in Brixton was BRIxton 2234. So you knew the exchange and needed to remember the 4 digits. Auntie was HITher Green 3151. This all changed in 1966 with 'all-figure numbers'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Likewise. Our phone number was ELTham 6973. Aunty was in ORPington. I seem to remember the GPO catch phrase was ANN - All Numbers Now. Still we'd better let this drop, since it's going waaaaay off topic.

Comment: @PeterJennings No more about phone numbers except to say that as I recall, some fringe-of-London places got added to the earlier dialling scheme with odd codes like 2 letters and 5 digits. My two aunties in Orpington, in Newstead Avenue and Cathcart Drive, had numbers like FN 12345 and MM 53679. FN was 'Farnborough (Kent)' exchange and MM was just 'Em Em'.

Comment: I’m not familiar with exactly which part of the IELTS requires memorization (could you please elaborate?) since that doesn’t seem very important for mastery of English, but I would say that practicing memorization is helpful.

Comment: I'd assume that 'Language Learning' is more appropriate for the recommendation of learning techniques.